# Tic Tac Toe Could not find method in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-emulator

**Context:**
I am making a Tic Tac Toe game where you press a button and then X or O appears on the button pressed. I have tried making it with the use of fragments since I want to have a navigation bar and, further down the line, I want to have a settings fragment to change stuff.

**Problem:**
I am getting java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method boardTapped(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'a1'

**What I've done:**

**fragment_game.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.bondesjakk.GameFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/grey_dark_1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Bondesjakk!"
            android:textColor="#64B5F6"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.059" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@color/grey_dark_1">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/a1"
                    style="@style/button" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@color/grey_dark_1">
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/a2"
                    style="@style/button" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@color/grey_dark_1">
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/a3"
                    style="@style/button" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@color/grey_dark_1">
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/b1"
                    style="@style/button" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@color/grey_dark_1">
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/b2"
                    style="@style/button" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/button6"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@color/grey_dark_1">
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/b3"
                    style="@style/button" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/button7"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@color/grey_dark_1">
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/c1"
                    style="@style/button" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/button8"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@color/grey_dark_1">
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/c2"
                    style="@style/button" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/button9"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@color/grey_dark_1">
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/c3"
                    style="@style/button" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                
app:constraint_referenced_ids="button1,button2,button3,button4,button5,button6,button7, 
button8,button9"
                app:flow_horizontalGap="1dp"
                app:flow_maxElementsWrap="3"
                app:flow_verticalGap="1dp"
                app:flow_wrapMode="chain"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

**Styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="square">
        <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">100dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/grey_dark_1</item>
    </style>

    <style name="button">
        <item name="android:onClick">boardTapped</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">40sp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**GameFragment.kt**

```
class GameFragment : Fragment() {

    enum class Turn {
        Nought, Cross
    }

    private var firstTurn = Turn.Cross
    private var currentTurn = Turn.Cross

    private var boardList = mutableListOf<Button>()

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentGameBinding

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<FragmentGameBinding>(inflater, 
    R.layout.fragment_game, container, false)

        boardList.add(binding.a1)
        boardList.add(binding.a2)
        boardList.add(binding.a3)
        boardList.add(binding.b1)
        boardList.add(binding.b2)
        boardList.add(binding.b3)
        boardList.add(binding.c1)
        boardList.add(binding.c2)
        boardList.add(binding.c3)

        return binding.root
    }

    fun boardTapped(view: View) {
        if(view !is Button)
            return
        addToBoard(view)
    }

    private fun addToBoard(button: Button) {
        if (button.text != "")
            return
        if(currentTurn == Turn.Nought) {
            button.text = NOUGHT
            currentTurn = Turn.Cross
        }
        else if (currentTurn == Turn.Cross) {
            button.text = CROSS
            currentTurn = Turn.Nought
        }
//    }

    //private fun setTurnLabel() {
      //  var turnText = ""
        //if (currentTurn == Turn.Cross)
          //  turnText = "Turn $CROSS"
        //else if (currentTurn == Turn.Nought)
          //  turnText = "Turn $NOUGHT"
    }

    companion object{
        const val NOUGHT = "O"
        const val CROSS = "X"
    }
}
```

Comment: don't even know if this is your problem, but why do you have `private lateinit var binding: FragmentGameBinding` and `val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<FragmentGameBinding>(inflater,...`

Comment: Implementet another persons code into mine, but have removed `private lateinit var binding: FragmentGameBinding` as it isnt needed